# why channel.getPeers() does not return all peers and only some of them?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have a network of 12 peers (6 orgs each one has 2 peers) but once I'm trying to retrieve all channel peers in node js app by using channel.getpeers() only it returns 2 orgs peers and I have to manually add the rest then send the proposal through all to sign.

I have checked all peers inside the cli and I saw all of them join the channel properly, do you have any idea why this method only returns 4 peers?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue recently, It seems to be the way the dynamic discovery behaves, I read through github code and found that they themselves use a method to retry query until function returns expected number of peers using [DefaultRetryableCodes](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/303f01c92fd71b2d0870932641b5c4460eb60202/pkg/common/errors/retry/defaults.go#L70) .

If you use go sdk the function can be found [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/768766943cc713f3ffcc439be3d4c99d4f72c6c5/test/integration/e2e/orgs/multiple_orgs_minconfig_test.go#L110). The same logic can be replicated by changing the to whatever requirement you have with the peers.